# send array objects from one array to another between classes ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, push, swap

so if I had 2 array that are in separate classes, what's the easiest way to remove all of the objects from the full array and add them to the empty array in another class. for example, this would be a before

```
class Red
  def initialize  
    @red_array = []
  end
end


class Blue
  @blue_array = [red_object, red_object2, red_object3]
end
```

and this would be the after

```
class Red
  def initialize  
    @red_array = [red_object, red_object2, red_object3]
  end
end


class Blue
  @blue_array = []
end
```

Comment: Is this just out of curiosity or do you have a reason for doing this? FYI: The first instance variable belongs to instances of Red, whereas the second instance variable belongs to the instance of Class, Blue.

Comment: I'm doing it because I am actually trying to model a cookie bakery.  In my actual code, I have a tray full of cookie objects that is part of an oven class and I want to put that array in the storefront class I have... So remove the items from the tray and place them in a storefront array... hope that helps!

Comment: What's the point of asking me if I'm curious and not answering my question.  This is my question so I should be expecting an answer.  Not you...

Comment: @RobMatthews that's not entirely how it works, often time questions don't have enough info so it';s necessary to ask the poster for explanation.

Comment: Your response regarding your object model was actually of use. I suspect the model you describe could be vastly improved. My suggestion would be to post your code on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and ask whether the model is suitable for your aims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your description your solution is kinda this

```
class Red
  attr_accessor :red_array

  def initialize
    @red_array = []
  end
end

class Blue
  attr_accessor :blue_array

  def initialize  
    @blue_array = []
  end
end

reds = Array.new(3,Red.new)

red = Red.new
red.red_array = reds

blue = Blue.new
blue.blue_array, red.red_array = red.red_array, blue.blue_array
```

Comment: `blue.blue_array, red.red_array = red.red_array, blue.blue_array`

Comment: @EricDuminil nice!! let me change it. Thanks!